# C++ linking error: 'libcairo.so: undefined reference to FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates'

Tags: centos, c++, dynamic-linking, cmake, cairo

I'm trying to build a C++ project via CLion and have been unable to get past this error in the linking process:

`` /lib/../lib64/libcairo.so: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates' ``

I'm wondering if anyone knows what the source of this issue could be - I've found a few similar questions in forums that were solved by the removal of a problematic package, but I have none of the aforementioned packages installed.

The version of cairo is cairo-1.15.12-4.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates` function was added to the Freetype2 library at around version 2.7 in October 2016. Your Freetype library, which is needed by Cairo, is probably too old.